# Someone who replies without actually making commitments?

Tags: single-word-requests

I can't remember a word to describe someone (maybe their action) of not committing oneself when asked.

I loosely remember a good one beginning with an 'e' I think.

ie, He was ???? when replying after being asked to commit himself to the task requested.

Comment: Evasive........?

Comment: Non-committal? Evasive?

Comment: Could you look at that again and consider what "Someone who replies without actually making commitments…" really means?

What would be wrong with avoider or dissembler, hedger or prevaricator, for instance?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**"equivocate"**

> use ambiguous language so as to conceal the truth or avoid committing
>   oneself. [-TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/equivocate)

Stop trying to equivocate and instead guarantee you'll fulfill my request, please.

Answer (score 2):

**"evasive"**

> tending or seeking to evade; avoiding the issue; not straightforward. -  [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/evasive)

When I asked him if he would help me with my spring cleaning, he gave an evasive answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply, that is, if you want, perhaps use "noncommittal."

That is direct and to the point.

Other adjectives like "guarded" or reserved" might work, too. It all really depends
on the feel you want to evoke.

Do you want to show that he/she is shy or directly noncommittal?
Cheers!

Answer (score -2):

'Obfuscatory' would work.  'Reticent' might work, as well.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your answer could be improved with an explanation of the differences between the two and examples of how they would be used, with links to suitable references. I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for an overview of how this site operates.

Comment: I might if I were to take this nonsense seriously; but I don't.  ;)